# Typescript doesn't understand first item in array of strings is a string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following functions:

```
const transitionGroup = (
  propertyName: string,
  durationMultiple = 1,
  timingFunction = 'linear',
  delayMultiple = 0,
): string => {
  // ...more logic here
  return [propertyName, duration, timingFunction, delay].join(' ');
};

const transition = (
  ...properties: (string | [string, number?, string?, number?])[]
): string => {
  const values = properties.map(property => {
    const propertyGroup = typeof property === 'string' ? [property] : property;
    return transitionGroup(...propertyGroup);
  });

  return `transition: ${values.join(', ')};`;
};
```

I get a type error on this line: `return transitionGroup(...propertyGroup);`

```
const propertyGroup: [string, (number | undefined)?, (string | undefined)?, (number | undefined)?] | string[]
Expected 1-4 arguments, but got 0 or more.ts(2556)
index.ts(6, 3): An argument for 'propertyName' was not provided.
```

Not sure exactly what's missing in my logic, but as far as I can tell, `propertyGroup` always ends up being an array where the first value is a string (which when spread into `transitionGroup` means the `propertyName` parameter gets the expected string value). Any ideas?

Comment: Seems it's complaining about the argument being supplied, so it seems the problem is with how `transition` is invoked.

Comment: @VLAZ in reality my code does work and my unit tests pass, so it seems Typescript is being picky about something and I can't understand why it's throwing this error.

Comment: the issue is here `return transitionGroup(...propertyGroup);` You haven't marked the arguments as optional, so TS is expecting those args to be present when calling the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely that `[property]` is inferred as type `string[]` and not as type `[string]`.  This is often a reasonable behavior, but in this case the compiler will forget that your `propertyGroup` variable will always be an array of at least one `string`.  If you explicitly annotate (or, more easily, [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)) that `[property]` is a `[string]`, it should start working for you:

```
const propertyGroup = typeof property === 'string' ? [property] as [string] : property;
return transitionGroup(...propertyGroup); // okay now
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBDSBLKLwHF4gK4AcYBeGACgCgYqZ8d8BTeKATwDlEBbegLhmnhRgA5gBpK1ACa4k6cAFlcAG3T5F9YjACMY6nBQdBQgGK4wwWWA0ByRYPqJ4VnZPqLEzBcpSr1JAAxiAJS8-IbEAHwwAN7iVAD0cTAAdCkcIPDqiiBCKMAwABaM9LEwGVDSlgDatCAMTGyc9CIwUjIYYJ4qas3oBsImZhbNEq7und5qALpJAFYggqRWMFaBANzkAL7rMOSgkLAIyBBo7RoUuilJNXXo9BC8pKHCMAA+MJVPojBguBwARowAPzNT7A76-AHwQGTQKVSbkYJ8BBhIiRGK6PbQGAAN0Qilwdw010YtwgSQ4iHwpGJ9Qi0RKGPAWJpLGweEIJBYDBAADMaHQScxiEQSFZPktAe8WcxJjBEBB3p9ZbxpdtdNQyhU4EhUBY2QRSJdpfr8GsYAkYCAANbub4gADuJQ2a3IJU18EsAANDrr2rwACRRXH4u6zeZgRbNFZbT3rLZAA)